# How do you pass an executable block as a parameter in Java?

Tags: java, refactoring

Is there a way to pass an executable block as a parameter to a static method? Is it possible at all? For example I have this method

```
public static void someMethod(boolean flag, Block block1, BLock block2) {
    //some other code
    if(flag)
        block1.execute();
    else block2.execute();
    //some other code
}
```

or something like that. It's actually more complicated than this, I just simplified the question. I am trying to refactor my project and I created a generic utility class that contains static methods that my classes use.

Comment: Look into the Command pattern.

Comment: I think the next version of Java has something like that, but right now, there's no language support for it, you have to wrap your logic inside a class, like how you do event handling in Swing applications and stuff.

Comment: Use a Runnable or a Future or the interface of your choice.

Comment: +1 for use of runnables.

Comment: You could make an interface that declares the `execute` method (or even use an existing one such as `Runnable`) and pass instances of that around.  They could be anonymous classes, or they could be your own classes that you define separately.

Comment: Before you refactor your code into static methods, you may wish to read this.  http://misko.hevery.com/2008/12/15/static-methods-are-death-to-testability/

Comment: FYI, Java 8 adds support for [lambda expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), which can be used in conjunction with single-method interfaces like `Runnable` and `Callable` to make the syntax for passing a "code block" very succinct.

Comment: @DaoWen the lambda expressions seem interesting. Gonna try it out too.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `Runnable` objects:

```
public static void someMethod(boolean flag, Runnable block1, Runnable block2) {
    //some other code
    if(flag)
        block1.run();
    else block2.run();
    //some other code
}
```

Then you can call it with:

```
Runnable r1 = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        . . .
    }
};
Runnable r2 = . . .
someMethod(flag, r1, r2);
```

EDIT (sorry, @Bohemian): in Java 8, the calling code can be simplified using lambdas:

```
someMethod(flag, () -> { /* block 1 */ }, () -> { /* block 2 */ });
```

You'd still declare `someMethod` the same way. The lambda syntax just simplifies how to create and pass the `Runnable`s.

Comment: If `.run()` will called from a working thread then code in run method will executed also on working thread? How is it possible to execute on main thread?

Comment: @János - To run on the main thread, you'd have to use a `Handler` and post the `Runnable` to it to be run by the handler rather than by the working thread code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an interface and pass objects from classes that implement that interface.  This is known as the Command pattern.

For example, you could have:

```
public interface IBlock
{
   void execute();
}
```

and an implementing class:

```
public class Block implements IBlock
{
    public void execute()
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

In Java 8 you will be able to pass lambda expressions such as predicates and functions which will make the code a little cleaner but essentially do the same thing.

Comment: Meh ... there's no need to invent new interfaces to do this.  Use `Runnable`.

Comment: use runnable sounds really not clean, just my point of view, never seen code using runnable that way

Comment: @Seb - What's not clean about it? `Runnable` was designed for exactly this kind of thing: passing a "block of code" that can be executed later (on another thread; at some time in the future; when certain conditions are met; etc.)