# How to refactor duplicate loops in multiple functions

Tags: java, loops, refactoring, duplicates

I am trying a TDD Tutorial and want to write good code. I faced a problem with duplicate code using loops.

My code looks like this:

```
public Board(int rows, int columns) {
    this.rows = rows;
    this.columns = columns;

    blocks = new Block[rows][columns];

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
          for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
              blocks[row][col] = new Block('.');
          }
    }
}

public boolean hasFalling(){
    boolean falling = false;

    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
            if(blocks[row][col].getChar() == 'X'){
                falling = true;
            }
        }
    }

  return falling;
}

 public String toString() {
    String s = "";
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
            s += blocks[row][col].getChar();
        }
        s += "\n";
    }
    return s;
}
```

As you see I am using the same for loop in different methods. Is there a way to avoid this and how are the approaches to avoid it ?

I am programming with Java.

Comment: You should get rid of `boolean falling = false;`, change `falling = true;` to `return true;`, and change `return falling;` to `return false;`... not an answer to the question, but just a comment...

Comment: @nhgrif that's a matter of taste. I personally would do it like him, since I thing return statements only (with some exceptions) be at the end of the method

Comment: @mvieghofer if you are only using one return then at least put a break in the if statement so you don't loop through the rest of the matrix when you already know the answer

Comment: The main point was he should break completely out of both `for` loops the instant he knows he can `return true` and avoid checking EVERY element.

Comment: @dkatzel Yep.  But he'd also need an `if` statement after the `inner for loop` to do `if(falling){break;}` to avoid iterating through more outer loops.  Simply `return true`-ing from the `inner loop` is WAY cleaner, imo.

Comment: @nhgrif Ok I could live with that :P

Comment: @mvieghofer I agree with you and method should have only return with different value, the value can be updated/modified, coming to above method should have break; so that unnecessary looping could be avoided.

Answer (score 6):

I think you are taking the "avoiding code duplication" idea of good code a bit too serious. It is true that you should avoid duplicate code since it makes it harder to read and maintain your code. But the loops are control statements and don't need to be avoided. It is similar to `if` statements, although you will use those a lot of times in your code, you will not put your if into an extra method.

Nevertheless, if you really want to do that, you can create a Runnable for each code block inside the for loop and create a method like this:

```
public void loop(Runnable runnable) {
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) {
          runnable.run();
      }
    }
}
```

You can then pass the Runnable you want to that method (also you probably need to pass the parameters to the runnable in some way). For more info see e.g. [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582807/java-pass-an-executable-block-as-a-parameter).

Comment: This kind of looks like a simplized version of Visitor pattern (but without trees). You are essentially adding in an event handler during your traversal. I like it!

Comment: Yes, it is basically the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how to simplify all the loops (and I'm not entirely sure you need/want to) but you can essentially eliminate most of the code in your hasFalling() method. Instead you could do this:

```
public boolean hasFalling(){
   return toString().contains('X');
}
```

Comment: Does it actually work? oh my god.. *opening Eclipse in a rush!*

Answer (score 0):

Two things of note:

IF you had the exact same `for loop` blocks in multiple places, you should factor that out into a function.

Also, IF you had the same exact loops, your architecture would be bad. You would just run the loop once and make it available to the things that care about it - probably via a getter function that will return the result of that loop to whatever calls for it.

In your case, all of that is irrelevant. Your `for loops` are not the same. Just because you have loops doesn't matter here...what you're doing with the loops is different.

You do have a big problem that makes your code hard to understand and can cause you a lot of difficulty. Learn about Dependency Injection. Your functions clearly need `blocks` in order to work, but this isn't clear until further inspecting the functions. If your functions need (depend on) `blocks`, then it should be passed into it.

Refactor like this `hasFalling(blocks)` to make things more clear. Global state is awful practice and will ruin you in the long run. Ditch globals and declare your dependencies.